# how to return count using mysql query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

i have a mysql table which contains

```
id,(primary key)

user_id,

**number**,

date
```

columns.I want a query which select count **number** for same date and same user_id.

for example,date column have 3 entries of 09/07/2014,then i want a query which return count 3.

my where condition contains only user_id

```
SELECT number,date FROM play_history WHERE  user_id =49
```

Thanks

Comment: what is meaning of same date?

Comment: date column contain same date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select `date`, count(`number`) as num_count
from play_history 
where user_id = 49
group by `date`
```